# repository class in NDBUNIT tutorial

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, ndbunit

I am trying to learn database unit testing from [ndbunit](http://code.google.com/p/ndbunit/wiki/QuickStartGuide) tutorial. All is going well. Except I do NOT understand how the author created the **CustomerRepository** class. Is there a tool that I can point to xsd file in the tutorial and auto generate the repository class? Even if I manually generate it, how would I go about doing it.

Please help.

Thanks

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
//I took out some code here...
    CustomerRepository repository = new CustomerRepository();
    Assert.AreEqual(2, repository.GetAllCustomers().Count);

}
```

**UPDATE**

I just used quick entity framework code to do quick data access as follows and it works great..thanks

```
        var context = new MyEntities();
        var query = from c in context.Customers select c ;
        var count = query.Count();

        Assert.AreEqual(2, count);
```

Comment: That's actually a great point that the sample in the getting-started section of the NDbUnit wiki *does* make an assumption about this.  We will make a point to try to make that more explicit in the guide.  Thanks~!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is assumption that CustomerRepository is a typical repository class. In your case this is something like

```
public class CustomerRepository
{
   public List<Customer> GetAllCustomers()
   {
       using (var context = new MyEntities() )            
           return context.Customers.ToList();
   }
}
```